# How to create a screen lock timer for Awesome WM?

Tags: screensaver, awesome

I've got an Ubuntu 12.04 system with Awesome WM, and I'd like the screensaver to work *like in Unity*:

1. **GNOME** Screensaver
2. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>** to lock
3. *N* minutes' **timeout which respects applications which temporarily disable the screensaver**

The keyboard shortcut was relatively easy:

```
-- Lock screen
awful.key(
    { "Mod1", "Control" },
    "l",
    function ()
        awful.util.spawn("gnome-screensaver-command --lock")
    end)
```

How do I solve point 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [xautolock](http://freecode.com/projects/xautolock):

> Xautolock monitors console activity under the X window system, and fires up a program of your choice if nothing happens during a user configurable period of time. You can use this to automatically start up a screen locker in case you tend to forget to do so manually before having a coffee break.

Something along the lines of:

```
xautolock -time 10 -locker "gnome-screensaver-command --lock"
```

The only application that I have found that doesn't respect `xautolock` is VLC; but mplayer works nicely with it.

Comment: Are you sure mplayer works nicely? I'm currently using mplayer-1.1(svn) and xautolock still triggers the locker while playing a video.

Comment: At the time I wrote this answer, yes mplayer worked with xautolock. An update sometime since has meant this is no longer the case. Hopefully, it is a temporary aberration.

Comment: VLC 2.1.5 works fine with `xautolock`

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly old post - but there's a good explanation on how to use xautolock together with i3lock here:

http://rabexc.org/posts/awesome-xautolock-battery

Comment: It is often customary to paste some of the important information from a link inline. You may want to consider doing so.